# How to exit GUI program by clicking the mouse in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, usleep

```
from graphics import *
def main():
    win = GraphWin("Shapes")
    center = Point(100, 100)
    circ = Circle(center, 30)
    circ.setFill("red")
    circ.draw(win)

    time.sleep(6) 

main()
```

So, I have installed (barely somehow) `graphics.py` by John Zelle so I can follow his book (An Introduction to Comp. Sci.) material for Chapter 5 Objects and Graphics.

I am writing all of my code in Sublime Text editor and when I want to compile, I go to `cmd` and type: `python` `"name_of_file".py` and start the program this way. 
In this package there is an object Window which is created by invoking `GraphWin()` (everything will be drawn here in the whole chapter), but that object stays visible for just a split of a second (my guess is because `main()` is executed and therefore it is done).

On the contrary, if I type all of required code (from that package) in the `cmd`, that Window object (and everything on it) stays visible the entire time.

It is very inconvenient to type in `cmd`. Is there something I can type inside main() to keep my work (Window object and everything else) visible, until lets say, I click a mouse or press Enter? I don't know how to implement that in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use getMouse() method of GraphWin object. It will wait until you click to continue execution.

```
from graphics import *
def main():
    win = GraphWin("Shapes")
    center = Point(100, 100)
    circ = Circle(center, 30)
    circ.setFill("red")
    circ.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()

main()
```